# Random background fadeIn() onto the current background

Tags: jquery, css

Here's my code: http://codepen.io/RycerzPegaza/pen/YypZza

I can't figure out how to add the fadeIn() effect onto the changing background when button is cliked (// FADE IN EFFECT in Javascript part).

/HTML/

```
  <body onload="randomquote(); randomcover()">
  <div class="container text-center"><div id="background" >
    <div id="qouteblock"><p id="content"></p></div></div>
<div class="row-fluid"><nav>
  <ul class="pager">
    <li onclick="randomquote()">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> a new qoute</button>
    </li>
  </ul></nav>
    </div></div>
</body>
```

/CSS/

```
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700|Amatic+SC:700&subset=latin,latin-ext);

body{
  background: url('http://i147.photobucket.com/albums/r293/VIEWLINER/REED/RFGF02.jpg~original') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;

}


.row-fluid {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}


p {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC';
  color: #DDDDDD;
  font-size: 250%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#qouteblock {

  position: relative;
}

#background{
  position: relative;
  top: 170px;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
}


.container {
  padding: 10px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 46%;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 18px !important;
}
```

/JAVASCRIPT/

```
// RANDOM BACKGROUND

randomcover = function(){
var covers = [];
covers[0] = " #222 url('http://i147.photobucket.com/albums/r293/VIEWLINER/REED/RFGF02.jpg~original') no-repeat center center fixed";
covers[1] = " #222 url('https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5255/5419581943_5826526eb4_o.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed";
covers[2] = " #222 url('http://www.splitshire.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/SplitShire-6272.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed"
 // FADEIN EFFECT 
  $("li").click(function() {
   var aCover = covers[Math.floor(Math.random()*covers.length)];
  $currImg = $("body").css({background:aCover}).fadeIn();
  });
};
// QUOTE MACHINE
randomquote = function() {
  var quotesArray = [];
quotesArray[0] = "One day I will find the right words, and they will be simple. <br> ― Jack Kerouac, The Dharma Bums";
quotesArray[1] = "Live, travel, adventure, bless, and don't be sorry. <br> ― Jack Kerouac";
quotesArray[2] = "My fault, my failure, is not in the passions I have, but in my lack of control of them. <br> ― Jack Kerouac";
quotesArray[3] = "the only people for me are the mad ones, the ones who are mad to live, mad to talk, mad to be saved, desirous of everything at the same time, the ones who never yawn or say a commonplace thing, but burn, burn, burn like fabulous yellow roman candles exploding like spiders across the stars. <br> ― Jack Kerouac";
quotesArray[4] = "The only truth is music. <br> ― Jack Kerouac";
quotesArray[5] = "The best teacher is experience and not through someone's distorted point of view. <br> ― Jack Kerouac";
quotesArray[6] = "Great things are not accomplished by those who yield to trends and fads and popular opinion. <br> ― Jack Kerouac"; 
quotesArray[7] = "Don't use the phone. People are never ready to answer it. Use poetry. <br> ― Jack Kerouac";
quotesArray[8] = "Will you love me in December as you do in May?<br> ― Jack Kerouac";
quotesArray[9] = "My witness is the empty sky. <br> ― Jack Kerouac";
quotesArray[10] = "Maybe that's what life is... a wink of the eye and winking stars. <br> - Jack Kerouac";
quotesArray[11] = "All human beings are also dream beings. Dreaming ties all mankind together. <br> - Jack Kerouac";
quotesArray[12] = "Forgive everyone for your own sins and be sure to tell them you love them which you do. <br> - Jack Kerouac";
  quotesArray[13] = "Because in the end, you won’t remember the time you spent working in the office or moving your lawn. Climb that goddamn mountain. <br> - Jack Kerouac";
  quotesArray[14] = "So therefore I dedicate myself, to my art, my sleep, my dreams, my labours, my suffrances, my loneliness, my unique madness, my endless absorption and hunger because I cannot dedicate myself to any fellow being. <br> - Jack Kerouac";
  quotesArray[15] = "Never Say a Commonplace Thing. <br> - Jack Kerouac";
  var newquote = quotesArray[Math.floor((Math.random()*15))];
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = newquote;
};
```

I would like to change the code as little as possible.

// thanks for advice :)

Comment: It's not possible in this way. There's no property like background opacity so you'd have to fade the whole element. And that won't work on `body` itself of course.

Answer (score 0):

fadeIn() just fades in the selected element, not any changed css values.

One solution would be to have a fullsize element for every background. Than you can fadeIn the new background and fadeOut the old.

Edit: How to add elements which cover the background

First, the CSS:

```
.bg-image {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(path/to/image.ext) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover
}
```

position fixed will make this element noch scroll-able. Even if you scroll the site, this element will stay at the same place on the screen.

Now add this as child elements of the body-tag and your good to go. As you want to change the background image, you should give the new elements different class which you than can use to set the right image via css and to fadeIn, fadeOut via javascript..

## Complete example (with js):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyVERy

Comment: So what should i do? How can I add a background property to any other element than the body element so it covers the site and lets me manipulate it?

Comment: first of all, don't wrap the divs inside each other. second: when you want to set a background image and its position, repeat etc., you have to use background:... and not background-image:... see: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyVERy